# vim,nerdtree,tab title don't show sorted number?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want the tab title to show sorted number,e.g. 1 area.txt ,2 country.txt,3.school.txt

so,I can goto any tab through number+`gt`command.but my vim shows like that,how to change it?

[image]

Comment: See `:help setting-tabline`. Also, you should probably avoid tab pages.

Comment: I am using a plugin that does what you want and some more: https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim